# Checking the convergence of the sequence: $\left(\frac{7n-3}{6n-5}\right)^n$

Tags: calculus, limits, convergence-divergence

I would like to obtain $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{7n-3}{6n-5}\right)^n .$$
I tried solving it but I didn't know how.
Maybe someone can help me ?

Comment: I think you can use Cauchy's root test.

Answer (score 3):

One may write, for $n\ge1$,
$$
\frac{7n-3}{6n-5}=\frac{7}{6}+\frac{17}{6(6n-5)}>\frac76
$$ giving
$$
\left(\frac{7n-3}{6n-5}\right)^n> \left(\frac{7}{6}\right)^n,\qquad n\ge1,
$$ which yields
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(\frac{7n-3}{6n-5}\right)^n=\infty.$$